# Instantiating defaults and variables

Tags: ruby, class, default, argument-error

So I have a class Ball. in Ball we have a method type. What I want to do is return a string of the type of ball. The tricky part: if ball has no argument, I want to return string "standard". This handles the no argument case just fine. However, the "football" case keeps throwing and ArgumentError 1 for 0 error. What I'm trying to do is set a default of "standard" for if there is no argument passed to type and to print a given argument (given it's a string). How do I fix the ArgumentError? I've tried using splat and just taking 0 arguments already. Neither worked

```
class Ball
  def type(ball="standard")
      ball
    end
end

Test.assert_equals Ball.new("football").ball_type, "football"
Test.assert_equals Ball.new.ball_type, "standard"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're calling `new` on `Ball`, you should rename the `type` method to `initialize`. This method will automatically be called when a new instance of `Ball` is constructed.

```
class Ball
  def initialize(ball = "standard")
    @ball = ball
  end
end
```

`@ball = ball` means that the `ball` argument is saved to the `@ball` instance variable.

It also looks like you want a method for accessing the ball type when you call `Ball.new.ball_type`:

```
class Ball
  def initialize ... end

  def ball_type
    @ball
  end
end
```

This method simply returns the value of the `@ball` instance variable, which was set in the `initialize` method.

After these modifications:

```
Ball.new("football").ball_type # => "football"
Ball.new.ball_type # => "standard"
```

Comment: So that did the trick, but is there any way to refractor it? Having 2 methods to handle a null case just feels..inefficient to me

Comment: @user3466773 This is about as simple as it gets. You could refactor `def ball_type ... end` to `attr_accessor :ball` if you don't mind having the `ball_type` method be renamed to `ball`.